# What is the Jewish perspective on play time?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study, performance-entertainment

The Jewish books of ethics are replete with the notion that any available moment that a Jew has he should be engaged in the study of Torah - and every moment available that is not utilized for the study of Torah is most likely used for idle matters which in turn leads to sins such as hurtful speech nor slander (paraphrased from Torat Habayit from the Chafetz Chaim).

Having said that is there any room in Judaism for an observant Jew to engage in personal hobbies, take trips to other countries, read secular literature or the like? If so are there any guidelines or Halachot for how and when on may engage in these activities?

Comment: "every moment available" What does that mean?

Comment: @DoubleAA, what are the possibilities?

Comment: Time not unconscious? Time not involved in absolute basic human needs? Time not possibly involved with anything of any value? Time not involved in your hobby? Something else? Why do I need to speculate???

Comment: Don't forget *derech eretz*.

Comment: Clearly, there was play time. In the *Bet Hamikdash*, the Levi'im played instruments or sang. There were always music players and artists around (Betzalel, for example). David's "hobby" was singing and playing the harp; He and King Solomon wrote poems / poetry. Clearly, there is a precedent for hobbies.

Comment: Seems that I'm not the only one that duplicates his own question :)

Comment: @DanF, I believe the Levi'im played for the purpose of a mitzvah not for self entertainment.